# Proving an inequality on $ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

**EDIT** : I have posted a proof below that needs to be reviewed.

**Some definitions**

Let $$\begin{array}{ccccc}
f & : & \mathbb R_+^* & \to & \mathbb R_+^* \\
 & & x & \mapsto & \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-tx}}{1+e^{-t}}dt \\
\end{array}$$

Let $$\begin{array}{ccccc}\forall n\in \mathbb N,  K_n & : & \mathbb R_+^* & \to & \mathbb R_+^* \\ 
& & x & \mapsto & \frac{\Gamma(n+1) \Gamma(x)}{\Gamma(n+x+1)} \\
\end{array}  $$

Note that equivalently $$ \forall n, \forall x>0, K_n(x)=\frac{n!}{x\times(x+1)\times\ldots\times(x+n)}$$

**Question**

Prove that
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb N, \forall x>0,f(x)\leq \frac{K_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}+\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}}$$

**Context**

I've been working thoroughly on $f$ over the past few days (see my other posts) in the scope of an assignment I got.

Here are some properties I have shown so far:

$$\forall x>0, f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+x}$$

$$\forall x>0, f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}}$$

**What I've tried**

Given the last identity, my question boils down to proving that 
$$ \forall n, \forall x>0 \;, \; 0 \leq \frac{K_{n+1}}{2^{n+1}} - \sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}} $$

I don't even know how to start... Induction maybe (since it's valid $\forall n$). I failed proving the case $n=0$ as well.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Something I noticed... $K_n(x) = B(n+1, x)$. (Where $B(x, y)$ is the [Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).) Since the Beta Function has some known properties, you might find something useful by researching that.  (Just a cursory idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the proof, in an (overly) simple way that makes me question its validity.

Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x>0$

We have that $$f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}}+\lim\limits_{M \to \infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^{M} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}}$$

For some fixed $M>n+1$ we have that
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{M} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{M}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\times\frac{k\times(k-1)\ldots\times(n+2)}{(x+k)\times(x+k-1)\ldots\times(x+n+2)}\times K_{n+1}(x)$$

Since $x>0$,
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{M}\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\times\frac{k\times(k-1)\ldots\times(n+2)}{(x+k)\times(x+k-1)\ldots\times(x+n+2)}\times K_{n+1}(x) \leq \frac{K_{n+1}(x)}{2^{n+1}}\times \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^k}$$

Hence
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{M} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}} \leq \frac{K_{n+1}(x)}{2^{n+1}}$$

This identity holding for all $M$, taking the limit on $M$ yields:
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}} \leq \frac{K_{n+1}(x)}{2^{n+1}}$$

Hence
$$f(x) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{K_k(x)}{2^{k+1}} + \frac{K_{n+1}(x)}{2^{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 0):

This an approach which tends to the form of the expected inequality :

[image]